# Dont know why i cant center web

Tags: html, css

So, in web-programming class (a few weeks ago) we started a project to make our own website. Now, most things are going fine, though I tried to center my page it didnt work. I don't know why it doesn't work either, I'm thinking it might be something in the codes that might block/counter it, but I don't know. I basically want the whole html centered. I used an ID which I named "wrap" on the div tag after the bgcolor tag as you will see.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Norskandi</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/norskandi.css">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#4A96AD">
<div id="wrap">
<a href="index.html"><IMG STYLE="WIDTH:1400px; HEIGHT:80px" src="../bilder/3_11.png"></a>


  <a  href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
/*window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
  openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
   } 
  }
 }
}*/
function geography() {
document.getElementById("geography").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
/*window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content1");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
  openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
   }
  }
 }
}*/
function anthems() {
document.getElementById("anthems").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
/*window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
  openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
   }
  }
 }
}*/
</script>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onmouseover="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">History</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="historysweden.html">Sweden</a>
        <a href="historynorway.html">Norway</a>
        <a href="historydenmark.html">Denmark</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown1">
      <button onmouseover="geography()" class="dropbtn">Geography</button>
        <div id="geography" class="dropdown-content1">
        <a href="geographysweden.html">Sweden</a>
        <a href="geographynorway.html">Norway</a>
        <a href="geographydenmark.html">Denmark</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown2">
      <button onmouseover="anthems()" class="dropbtn">Anthems</button>
        <div id="anthems" class="dropdown-content2">
        <a href="anthemssweden.html">Sweden</a>
        <a href="anthemsnorway.html">Norway</a>
        <a href="anthemsdenmark.html">Denmark</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap{
 width: 800px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Instead of margin left and right, try `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Juan-Ferres here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d33a7zmu/2/) that may help you.  Another great resource is [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and look at the class container in their examples.  As a few have pointed out though the key is `margin: 0 auto` or something like `margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px` but then you need to be more exacting with your width.

Answer (score 0):

Try `justify-content: center` in you CSS code

Answer (score 0):

Your `#wrap` div is being centered on the site. However, for resolutions smaller than 800px, you will see it overflows horizontally.

You may think it's not centered due to your `img` tag having an inline style of `width: 1400px` which makes it extend beyond the actual container div.

Here's a fiddle with that tag removed (try not to use inline styles on your HTML for proper *separation of concerns* as in, CSS in css files, and HTML in html files). https://jsfiddle.net/dm3bmpas/

I've also replaced `width: 800px` for `max-width: 800px` and `width: 100%` so your container takes up to 800px on resolutions big enough but for smaller resolutions it takes all the available width; this is a common responsive pattern.

Finally, just in case, if you want your text to be centered inside your div, the rule you're looking at is `text-align: center` on your #wrap div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
#wrap{
     width: 800px;
     margin:0px auto;
}
```